# When were the "War Relief Toy Works" set up and by whom?

Tags: united-kingdom, business-history

There are a number of toys in existence - particularly Noah's Arks - which originate from the 'War Relief Toy Works', which was based in Stoke Newington, a suburb of London, UK.

A representative picture of one of these can be seen [here](http://www.vectis.co.uk/Page/ViewLot.aspx?LotId=525407).

There are references to the Works in [1922](http://www.gracesguide.co.uk/War_Relief_Toy_Works), 1929 ([here](http://tcqdev.edina.ac.uk/search/location/2584-Dundee/commodity/437830-Spero%20Firewood/document/161482) and [here](http://www.gracesguide.co.uk/War_Relief_Toy_Works)), [1934](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/SearchUI/Details?uri=C7812692), and [1944](http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/written_answers/1944/oct/27/ex-servicemen-benevolent-organisations).

Anyone know who set up the Works, how were they organised and whether anyone who worked there wrote memoirs?

Any information you could point me to would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 3):

There is little credible information about War Relief Toy Works. The knowledge seems to be shared to whoever owns a piece.

Based on some of my research I believe that "War Relief Toy Works" was a charity created to aid injured soldiers. The toys would be made by wounded soldiers in World War One and possibly World War Two but is unlikely or less successful. These toys would then be sold and profits given to programs that aid rehabilitation. "War Relief Toy Works" made an appearance at the 1922 and 1929 British Industries Fair. Unfortunately I was unable to find any information there. 
I recommend contacting some of the sellers or owners of the Arks and doing more research about the 1922 and 1929 British Industries Fair.

---

http://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/war-relief-toy-works-noahs-ark-c1918-313146331

War Relief Toy Works Noah's Ark c1918. 
This lovely model was made in England by injured soldiers 
from The First World War. 
The factory was called 'War Relief Toy Works' and was based 
in Stoke Newington, London. 
The ark has a warm feel to it as though it needs to belong in a 
loving home. To imagine that it was made by once fit and proud 
soldiers, reduced to disability by the horrors of The First World 
War. 
This is a most collectible piece, I feel so strongly about this lovely 
ark that when it is sold I will make a donation to ABF, the soldiers 
charity in memory of the soldiers whose skillful making of these 
models helped them on the road to rehabilitation. 
Length: 23"inches x Height 13"inches x Depth 7"inches

http://www.gracesguide.co.uk/War_Relief_Toy_Works

110 Church Street, Stoke Newington, London, N16. (1922)
Ditto Address. Telephone: Clissold 4225. (1929)
1922 Listed Exhibitor - British Industries Fair. Manufacturers of Noah's Arks, Solid Wood Animals; Windmill Sets (wood); Farmhouse Sets (wood); Ornamental Wooden Bricks. (Stand No. J.127)
1929 Listed Exhibitor - British Industries Fair. Manufacturers of Noah's Arks with hand-carved and coloured wood animals. Building Bricks in wood boxes, etc., and Farm Sets with hand-cut wood animals. Hand-carved Skittles in boxes. (Stand No. C.59)e

Comment: Thanks Athena - your comments amplify, but don't really add to the information contained in the links given in the question. You mention you've done research. Can you cite sources? For instance, you claim that 'These toys would then be sold and profits given to programs that aid rehabilitation.' What evidence do you have for this? I'd be very interested to find out.

Comment: I've cited all the reasouces I could find. To be honest, if you really want to know more about them, you'd have more luck with the owners.